# Modify datetime axis of a dataframe stacked histogram + Matplotlib DateFormatter issues with UTC datetime

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that contains time and sentiment. The time variable is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

I want to plot a stacked histogram of the sentiment with 5 mins bars.

The below code works, but the x axis is too busy. I want to display only 30 minutes intervals on the x axis and still have each 5 mins bars.

Can you please help me achieve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df.groupby([df.time.dt.floor('5Min'),'Sentiment']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

**EDIT #1**

I think the following code is in the right direction, but it seems that the mdates.Dateformatter is not returning the proper dates. Link to data sample : https://pastebin.pl/view/52b65e7b

```
df = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv", nrows=999)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True)
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')


df.groupby([df.time.dt.floor('5Min'),'Sentiment']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)


plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

**EDIT #2**

In my dataframe, I have another column named 'close' that I want to display as a line on the same axis. How do I overlay a line for df['close'] on this graph?

Comment: side-note: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True)` should do, you don't need the line before.

Comment: Noted - thanks for the note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to thin out the time series on its X axis in a grouped graph, it is easiest to update it with labels created as often as you need. The change from your code is that the time zone information is removed because it makes the labels on the X-axis longer. We also use the resample function to get a sampling every 5 minutes. If the data is different, please correct it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv', sep=',', nrows=999)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = df.groupby(['Sentiment']).resample('5min').size().unstack().T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(14,9))

df_ts = df.groupby(['Sentiment']).resample('5min').size().unstack().T
labels = [ str(x) if (x.minute == 30) | (x.minute == 0) else '' for x in df_ts.index]

ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]