# Problems with UTC datetime - how to fit a colon - time data '2021-03-11 09:30:01-05:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %z'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert the string `'2021-03-11 09:30:01-05:00'` to a datetime using the following code.

It seems that my string as a colon (`:`) between 05 and 00 and that this colon is not in the default `%z` date format.

How can I convert my string to an EST datetime?

```
df = pd.read_csv(mypath + "ticks.csv")
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'")
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: You have two sets of quotes around your format string. Try instead: `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')`

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I get the error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" when running df['time'] = df['time'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern'). Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't get that error just with that one example string. I'm wondering if there might be some non-datetimelike values in the CSV file...

Comment: I don't understand, even when I use : df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z',  errors='coerce') I get the error Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values... can I upload you my CSV file somewhere?

Comment: Can you please have a look at the file here : https://file.io/Q9u8XRBpKH25

Comment: Hm, maybe https://pastebin.com/ is the simplest way? I'm not sure I'm going to be able to figure it out, though, because I've just tried a couple of different data; and nothing is producing that error.

Comment: Also pastebin link if you prefer viewing text file : https://pastebin.pl/view/52b65e7b

Comment: Ok, I retrieved your file. I was able to perform the conversion. I will write an answer showing the steps in the hopes it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following slight variation from what you were trying is working fine for me.

```
df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True)
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Result:

```
In [115]: df['time']
Out[115]: 
0       2021-03-11 09:30:01-05:00
1       2021-03-11 09:30:02-05:00
2       2021-03-11 09:30:14-05:00
3       2021-03-11 09:30:14-05:00
4       2021-03-11 09:30:14-05:00
                   ...           
35518   2021-03-15 15:59:53-04:00
35519   2021-03-15 15:59:54-04:00
35520   2021-03-15 15:59:56-04:00
35521   2021-03-15 15:59:56-04:00
35522   2021-03-15 15:59:57-04:00
Name: time, Length: 35523, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks a lot... would you mind looking at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619902/modify-datetime-axis-of-a-dataframe-stacked-histogram... you can use the same file,,, I'm having issue with matplotlib... I'll buy you a coffee ;)